# Efficient computation of $\sum_{i=1}^{i=\left \lfloor {\sqrt{N}} \right \rfloor}\left \lfloor \frac{N}{i^{2}} \right \rfloor$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, number-theory, summation, modular-arithmetic

I have tried to find a closed form but did not succeed but is there an efficient way to calculate the following expression

$\sum_{i=1}^{i=\left \lfloor {\sqrt{N}} \right \rfloor}\left \lfloor \frac{N}{i^{2}} \right \rfloor$

So Far I have noticed the following

$\sum_{i=1}^{i=\left \lfloor {\sqrt{N}} \right \rfloor}\left \lfloor \frac{N}{i^{2}} \right \rfloor = \sum_{i=1}^{i=\left \lfloor {\sqrt{N}} \right \rfloor}\left \lfloor \frac{N-N \mod i^{2}}{i^{2}} \right \rfloor = N *\left \lfloor {\sqrt{N}} \right \rfloor - \sum_{i=1}^{i=\left \lfloor {\sqrt{N}} \right \rfloor} N \mod i^{2}$

I want to solve it in either log(N) or as a closed form

Comment: Note that the upper limit of summation can go higher, since after $i=\lfloor\sqrt{N}\rfloor$, the summands will be $0$.

Then this is the same as [OEIS A013936](https://oeis.org/A013936), which allows the upper limit to go all the way to $N$. There are some results there, but no explicit formula.

The terms are very close to [OEIS A145353](https://oeis.org/A145353).

Comment: I tried finding to come to a from the links, but I wasn't able to come up with anything. Do you think that i have to calculate (Expression) mod 1000000007 changes anything and helps to get a more computationally feasible solution?

Comment: Third question about this sum, or something very like it, today. Is there a run on floor functions?

Comment: Your summation is bounded between $\frac{\pi^2}{6} N-\sqrt{n} \leq Y_S  \leq \frac{\pi^2}{6} N -  2 \sqrt{N}$ for all $N \geq 10$, for sure one can reduce $-2\sqrt{N}$ the constant may be less than $2$ but bigger than $ 1.60772$

Comment: I'm guessing that it's a competition problem. More of it are incoming. Will try to link to this.

Comment: @CalvinLin You're right, Everyone is probably trying to solve this question(https://www.codechef.com/APRIL20A/problems/PPDIV) and it is a sub part of the problem.

Answer (score 5):

One approach to improving the efficiency of calculating this would be to take 
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left\lfloor\frac{N}{i^2}\right\rfloor$$ and ask how many times is the summand a $1$? How many times is it a $2$? And so on. Keep reading to the end, and this reduces the computation from $O(n^{1/2})$ time to $O(n^{1/3})$ time.

$\left\lfloor\frac{N}{i^2}\right\rfloor=1$ whenever $1\leq\frac{N}{i^2}<2$. So whenever $\sqrt{N}\geq i>\sqrt{\frac{N}{2}}$. There are $\left\lfloor\sqrt{N}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\sqrt{\frac{N}{2}}\right\rfloor$ such values of $i$.

So the sum is the same as $$\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor\sqrt{N/2}\rfloor}\left\lfloor\frac{N}{i^2}\right\rfloor+1\cdot\left(\left\lfloor\sqrt{N}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\sqrt{\frac{N}{2}}\right\rfloor\right)$$

The original expression has $\lfloor\sqrt{N}\rfloor$ nonzero terms. Now it is written with $\lfloor\sqrt{N/2}\rfloor+2$ terms, which is an improvement if $N$ is at least $64$. You could continue like this, counting how many times $2$ appears in the original sum.

$\left\lfloor\frac{N}{i^2}\right\rfloor=2$ whenever $2\leq\frac{N}{i^2}<3$. So whenever $\sqrt{\frac{N}{2}}\geq i>\sqrt{\frac{N}{3}}$. There are $\left\lfloor\sqrt{\frac{N}{2}}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\sqrt{\frac{N}{3}}\right\rfloor$ such values of $i$.

So the sum is the same as $$\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor\sqrt{N/3}\rfloor}\left\lfloor\frac{N}{i^2}\right\rfloor+1\cdot\left(\left\lfloor\sqrt{N}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\sqrt{\frac{N}{2}}\right\rfloor\right)+2\cdot\left(\left\lfloor\sqrt{\frac{N}{2}}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\sqrt{\frac{N}{3}}\right\rfloor\right)$$
$$=\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor\sqrt{N/3}\rfloor}\left\lfloor\frac{N}{i^2}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\sqrt{N}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\sqrt{\frac{N}{2}}\right\rfloor-2\left\lfloor\sqrt{\frac{N}{3}}\right\rfloor$$
Now there are $\lfloor\sqrt{N/3}\rfloor+3$ terms, which is an improvement over the previous version if $N$ is at least $72$. Keep going like this $M$ iterations, and the sum is equal to $$\sum_{i=1}^{\left\lfloor\sqrt{N/(M+1)}\right\rfloor}\left\lfloor\frac{N}{i^2}\right\rfloor+\sum_{j=1}^M\left\lfloor\sqrt{\frac{N}{j}}\right\rfloor-M\left\lfloor\sqrt{\frac{N}{M+1}}\right\rfloor$$ which is a sum with $\left\lfloor\sqrt{\frac{N}{M+1}}\right\rfloor+M+1$ terms, each of which has roughly the same computational complexity as the terms in the original sum. For a given $N$, there is an $M$ that minimizes this count of summands. If we ignore the floor function, calculus optimization leads us to $M\approx(N/4)^{1/3}$. And using that value for $M$, the number of terms in the summation is $\left(\sqrt[3]{2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{4}}\right)N^{1/3}$.  That would be a noteworthy improvement over the original summand count of $\sqrt{N}$.